# HTML PHP Array multidimensional

Tags: php, html, array

Necesito construir un array multidimensional con una tabla html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

  $ciutats = array
(
    array('Tòquio','Japó','Àsia'),
    array('Mèxic', 'DF', 'Amèrica'),
    array('Nova York', 'EUA', 'Amèrica'),
    array('Mumbai', 'India', 'Ásia'),
    array('Seül', 'Corea', 'Àsia'),
    array('Xangai', 'Xina', 'Àsia'),
    array('Lagos', 'Nigeria', 'Àfrica'),
    array('Buenos Aires', 'Argentina', 'Amèrica'),
    array('el Caire', 'Seül', 'Corea'),


);
    

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No me sale la solución al ejercicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a ver si esto te sirve ;)

```
<?php

$ciutats = array(
    array('Tòquio','Japó','Àsia'),
    array('Mèxic', 'DF', 'Amèrica'),
    array('Nova York', 'EUA', 'Amèrica'),
    array('Mumbai', 'India', 'Ásia'),
    array('Seül', 'Corea', 'Àsia'),
    array('Xangai', 'Xina', 'Àsia'),
    array('Lagos', 'Nigeria', 'Àfrica'),
    array('Buenos Aires', 'Argentina', 'Amèrica'),
    array('el Caire', 'Seül', 'Corea'),
);

    echo "<table style=\"border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;\">";
for ($r=0; $r < count($ciutats); $r++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($ciutat=0; $ciutat < count($ciutats[$r]); $ciutat++) { 
        echo "<td style=\"text-align: center;width: 8em; border: 1px solid black; padding-left: 4px;\">" . $ciutats[$r][$ciutat] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Utilizalo como base para tu ejercicio, Suerte :)

> Corrijo
>
> > Asi se añaden el encabezado que se me habia olvidado

```
<?php

$ciutats = array(
    array('Tòquio','Japó','Àsia'),
    array('Mèxic', 'DF', 'Amèrica'),
    array('Nova York', 'EUA', 'Amèrica'),
    array('Mumbai', 'India', 'Ásia'),
    array('Seül', 'Corea', 'Àsia'),
    array('Xangai', 'Xina', 'Àsia'),
    array('Lagos', 'Nigeria', 'Àfrica'),
    array('Buenos Aires', 'Argentina', 'Amèrica'),
    array('el Caire', 'Seül', 'Corea'),
);

    echo "<table style=\"border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;\">";
    echo "<tr style=\"width: 8em; border: 1px solid black; padding-left: 4px;\"><th>Ciudad</th><th>Pais</th><th>Continente</th><tr>";
for ($r=0; $r < count($ciutats); $r++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($ciutat=0; $ciutat < count($ciutats[$r]); $ciutat++) { 
        echo "<td style=\"text-align: center;\">" . $ciutats[$r][$ciutat] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracis Ruben! Si es lo que buscaba, Like! Lo único que pondría (Ciutat pais continent) encima la tabla para hacerlo mas comprensible pero el contenido que es lo importante es eso es perfecto ! Moltes gràcies!

Comment: Ya lo he corregido. Se me habia olvidado, ahora ya esta mas completo

Comment: **Exacto ahora ya de dulce!!** Saludos y suerte en tu camino como programador!!